# So which "wich'" is it?

Tags: etymology

It's generally not confusing to most the obvious differences between a sandwich, a witch and the word "which", but are they related in any way? While a *sandwich* can be defined jokingly as,"in my mouth; piece of food that doesn't exist anymore" etc. most of everyone knows that a sandwich is basically any combination or form of substance, in between two slices or pieces of bread. But what about a *witch*? I'm guessing because the term is widely talked about in the bible, it is very old, and it most likely originated before the term sandwich.

And to add another substance form to the mix, I'd also like to introduce the word *which*. The term can be used in such a way it follows the requirements of being a pronoun ("Which of these ~", "Which one of ~"), or an adjective ("Which car ~", "Which type of ~").

So, are those three words related in anyway, or is it all just coincidence they sound the same, mind you, not in terms of spelling.

And please forgive me if this isn't English-related or doesn't have any involvement with the English language subject this site is all about.

Comment: You have asked a wide and diverse question. Let's just deal with ***sandwich*** first. The *sandwich* is believed to be named named after John Montagu, 4th Earl of Sandwich (1718-1792), whom it is said was addicted to gambling and hit upon the then novel idea of taking slices of meat between bread, so that he could continue at the card table whilst eating. Sandwich is a small town on the coast in the county of Kent. The *...wich* in its name is a variant of the old Norse *wick* meaning a small bay or inlet.   My guess is that this has no connection whatever to *witch*, nor to *which*.

Comment: @WS2 I still don't feel this answers the question, as to why do they sound the same then? Is it just a lucky chance across continents that they created the same sound and used it?

Comment: Since when do they talk about witches in the Bible?! Yes, it's just coincidence that the latter half of the word _sandwich_ sounds like the word _witch_. Just like it's coincidence that the last part of _trampoline_ sounds like the word _lean_. (_Which_ doesn't dound the same as _witch_ to quite a lot of speakers, by the way.)

Comment: If you haven't read the bible, and/or not read the definition of a witch, it also falls under the word necromancer. People talked these witches/necromancers, and since they could, "talk to the dead", God banished them to Hell, with the customers that came to them. @JanusBahsJacquet Don't jump to conclusions please. I'm taking answers as calmly as possible and I just want to have a little picked up word trivia.

Comment: If you've actually read the bible, it makes several references to necromancers, which happens to be a specific, or wide ranged use for the term witch. Because necromancers could supposedly "communicate with the dead," they were banished to Hell, along with the people who came to see them for assistance. @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: Most Americans don't use _wich_ as short for _sandwich_, but there is no difference in pronunciation between _which_ and _witch_, no matter what Americans believe they say. They're not listening.

Comment: Be careful what you claim. There may be only one true mention of a witch in the Bible, who is the Witch of Endor, and she is used by God to tell Saul the truth. In a c.1250 translation of "Exodus," witches is used of the Egyptian midwives who save the newborn sons of the Hebrews: "Ðe [wicches](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=witch&searchmode=none) hidden hem for-ðan, Biforen pharaun nolden he ben." Anyway, this is Gen. Ref.

Comment: @JohnLawler Not true.  Not all dialects of English exhibit the wine-whine merger.

Comment: I said Americans speaking American English. Many Americans believe they say _witch_ differently from _which_ (or _whale/wail, where/wear, whine/wine,_ etc). But actual recordings show they don't in ordinary speech.

Comment: @medica, though that single mention isn't a case where the word is used in the KJV, which is probably the translation with the most impact on Modern English. In that she is "a woman that hath a familiar spirit at Endor".

Comment: Keep in mind that English derives from a half-dozen different languages.  Even if "the rules" for each of those languages separately forbid similar-sounding words (and even if none of the sounds have changed in the intervening 800 or so years), you're still bound to get "conflicts".

Comment: @JohnLawler - Though I continue to insist that I say sounds that others claim not to hear, I readily agree that I say "which" and "witch" nearly identically.  I *might* sneak a hair more "T" sound into "witch" if I'm attempting to speak distinctly, but most of the time not.

Comment: @JohnLawler I also meant American English. The distinction most definitely exists in some deep Southern dialects, unless you want to argue that they aren't speaking American English.

Comment: There are always dialects that preserve some distinction. RP preserves a distinction between the vowel in _man_ and the stressed vowel in _baNAna_ that American English has lost completely. For virtually all Americans, there's no difference between /hw/ and /w/, just as there's no difference between _marry_ /'mæri/, _Mary_  /'meri/, and _merry_ /'mɛri/, except for people from Rhode Island.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The point about no witches in the bible is a good one (or perhaps on just one in the KJV). Witches did not really exist in Europe much before the Reformation. In fact the late 16th and 17th centuries are the great age of witches. Historians have opined various reasons for this, not least that, in Early Modern society traditional village structures were breaking down and it became easier for individuals to become isolated. It was also an age which had begun using a legal system for redress, and accusations of witchery could yield fruit against someone thought undesirable.

Comment: @WS2 and the King James Version was after all commissioned by King James, self-professed expert in witchcraft, author of "Daemonologie, In Forme of a Dialogie, Divided into three Bookes. By James Rx" self-professed survivor of an assassination attempt by witches, under whose reign in Scotland the first real persecution of alleged witches began during which he personally attended the torture of suspects. In all the KJVs commissioner was not the most neutral person on such topics as whether φαρμακεία should be translated as "witch". Still, it does tell us that English had the word *witch* then.

Comment: @JonHanna Good points. Indeed I'm told by an historian of the KJV that it is politically loaded. Whilst 'just and honourable kings' abound, the word 'tyrant' is barely mentioned.

Comment: @WS2 very definitely, and aside from likely conscious efforts of "well, what would our boss the witch-hating king think" it inevitably reflects the biases of people from the time and of course lacks the benefits of subsequent research. Ironically as a witch its my favourite translation, but then as a witch its scriptural merits are irrelevant since I don't believe any of it; I just like its language.

Answer (score 6):

> It's generally not confusing to most the obvious differences between a sandwich, a witch and the word "which", but are they related in any way?

No.

*Sandwich* the food comes from *sandwich* the town (quite likely via the 4th Earl of Sandwich). Many English place names have *-wich* at the end, and some have the related *-wick* or *-wych* and a few used to have one and since lost it (*Jorwic* is now called *York*). It comes from the Old English *wic* meaning "place", "dwelling" or "bay", or the related Old Norse *vic* meaning the same thing (if named by Vikings). Further back it was a Germanic borrowing from *vicus* from which we have *vicinity*.

As the language changed the Old English rule that *c* following *i* or prior to *i* or *e* (but with some exceptions like *ascian*) was a /tʃ/ sound changed and so the later forms either became a /k/ or else the spelling changed to *ch* as that combination of letters is used for /tʃ/ in Middle and Modern English.

In some dialects you might perhaps still find *wick* as a word meaning "town" or "village" though it's probably completely obsolete on its own.

*Witch* is originally *wicca* (or *wicce* in the female form). Again the spelling changed to *wicche* and later *witch* to match the later spelling rules. While there is some debate about just what the etymology of *wicca* is going back prior to Old English, it is certainly quite separate from *wic* and *vic*.

*Which* comes from Old English *hwilc*. Since the difference between "w" and "wh" (in those days, "hw") words was much more distinct in Old English, that and the *l* would mean that it wouldn't even be seen as coincidentally similar in those days. Even today it sounds quite different in some accents.

Incidentally, there is also *wych* used of several types of tree (*wych hazel*, sometimes written *witch hazel* and *wych elm*). It's also from Old English (*wice* meaning supple or pliant, compare *wicker*) but also not connected to any of the above. (There is a theory of the etymology of *wicca* prior to Old English that would have them as distant cousins, but its not considered the most likely etymology).

> But what about a witch? I'm guessing because the term is widely talked about in the bible, it is very old, and it most likely originated before the term sandwich.

Be careful about this as a guide. It is certainly true that the King James Version of the bible is a valuable resource for looking at Early Modern English, not every word in English of the time was used in it. (Later translations are pretty much useless in this regard). While *sandwich* as an item of food is no older than its invention in the 18th century, *Sandwich* the town is also from Old English and its *-wich* ending goes back to the very beginnings of the language.

Also you're incorrect in saying the term is widely talked about; there are ten uses of the word or related words like *witchcraft*.

Comment: great job - now get back to your bio!

Comment: It is a sobering thought that had Lord Cardigan been a gambler, and the Earl of Sandwich a lover of woollen waistcoats, instead of the other way around, then today we would all be eating cardigans and wearing sandwiches!